# How do I translate these verbs?

Tags: translation

I recently saw these phrases (from the song 我要你的爱):
你为什么不走过来 (I think it basically means: Why won't you come here)
你为什么不说出来 (I think it basically means: Why won't you say it)
为什么不肯说 (I think it basically means: Why don't you feel like saying it)
I concluded their meanings from context but am still confused as to what the meaning of their predicate is: What exactly does 走过来, or 说出来, or 肯说 mean? How would they be translated? Are they colloquial expressions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- "你为什么不走过来?" --> 你(you) 为什么(why) 不走过来(don't come over) --> "Why you don't come over?"
- "你为什么不说出来" --> 你(you) 为什么(why) 不说出来 (not speak out) --> "Why you don't say it?"
- "为什么不肯说" --> 为什么(why) 不肯说 (unwilling to say) --> Why do you  unwilling to say?"

> What exactly does 走过来, or 说出来, or 肯说 mean?

'**走过来**'  means '**come over** (by foot)'

'**说出来**' means 'speak (it) out' = "**say it**"

'**肯**说' means '**willing** to speak/ say'

*Depend on context 肯 could mean 'willing to' or 'agree to'*

*In English, you must put the question form before the subject. For example, you can't say "you why don't come over?" instead of  " why you don't come over?"*

*However, in Chinese, question form and the subject can switch place.  e.g. "(你)为什么不走过来?" = "为什么(你)不走过来?"*

Answer (score 2):

These are very common expressions, not dialect.

你为什么不走过来
Why don't you come on over?
你为什么不说出来
Why don't you say anything / what you feel / what's on your mind?
为什么不肯说
why don't you want to say anything?

These are easier to put into German, English has lost these kind of verb forms:
走过来
herlaufen (walk over from)  (her (spoken like 'hair': indicates from somewhere towards the speaker)
说出来
aussprechen (speak out = speak, say something) (aus (spoken like 'ouse' from 'mouse': out)

肯：agree, willing, consent, 不肯：unwilling, disagree
不肯说
unwilling (to) speak